# Best way to parallelize for loops in R?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm trying to find out one way to parallelize the next for loop:

```
lambda_pois <- 25
for(k  in 1:100000){
        N=rpois(1, lambda_pois)
        S=0
        for(i in 1:N){
           u=runif(1)
           S=uniroot(f.inv,c(0,35000000000))$root+S
        }
        P[k]=S
        print(k)
    }
```

As you can see, the first for is the one where the hard things are happening, so I was trying to parallelize is using this:

```
library(foreach)
library(doMC)
cores_to_use <- detectCores() 
cores_to_use
registerDoMC(cores_to_use - 2)
```

and then changing the first for with a foreach like:

```
foreach(k=1:100000) %dopar%{
```

with a CPU with 32 cores I'm not having the speedup necessary, it was taking 7 days in serial, now it takes aproximately 7 hours, can I still have a better speedup maybe using another kind of parallelism? GPU's or something like that but still using R???

Comment: 7 days -> 7 hours = 24 times speedup. Seems like 30 workers (cores - 2). Do you want linear speedup?))

Comment: Problem is, they the hardware used when moving this to production is gonna have less cores for sure... and this in a E7 machine with 4 CPU's and 8 cores each.

Comment: How does the performance change when you use 32 cores?

Comment: Martin, it is the inverse of a distribution function, I'm trying to approximate the inverse value of that dist. function.

Comment: In two dimensions? Establish a much less dense grid (100 x 100?), and interpolate with various levels of sophistication (linear, quadratic, splines).